# Paypal redirection issue

Tags: django, paypal, django-paypal, django-oscar

[image]Am using django-oscar-paypal for my new project,once i do the payment it successfully takes me 
to paypal sandbox site,after clicking continue button the page is redirected to

URL shown:
https://site.com/checkout/paypal/preview/63/?token=EC-9DM94343UB249654R&PayerID=SDH6FPG9CK72L
This page shows 'SSL Connection error'.How do i remove https from the link.

How do i fix this??Need Help

I just need to remove https from the link,i think that might work,how do i remove that.If this is some other issues.PLease provide help

Comment: Can you share the snapshot of the error?

Comment: i have updated with screenshot

Comment: put this in settings : 
PAYPAL_CALLBACK_HTTPS=False

Answer (score 1):

The ReturnURL is set in the SetExpressCheckout request, so you just need to adjust it there.

Looking at https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar-paypal/blob/master/paypal/express/gateway.py you can see it's using a variable called "return_url".  Just need to find where that is getting set and adjust it accordingly.

Comment: i have removed https by settings PAYPAL_CALLBACK_HTTPS=False but am getting url in my console as  http://0.0.0.0:8000/checkout/paypal/preview/78/.This is correct.But when page is redirected to this url is shows basket is empty and my basket was shown correctly in paypal website.how can i solve this?

Comment: Sounds like you're losing session data upon return.

Comment: Do you know where is this problem happening

Comment: My guess would be you've got something else going on with SSL and http:// vs. https://  I know I've seen people losing their session data when they start on http:// and are then returned to https:// once they're back from PayPal, for example.

Comment: so you are telling that its bacuase of http and i have to replace back to https,will it resolve any issues,is there any thing for reference?

Comment: No, I'm saying that if that were happening that could be why you're losing session data.  If that's not happening then it must be something else.  It could be any number of things.  If you are in fact using session data then you just need to debug and track the value of those values up to the point where they get emptied so you can see what's doing it.